# Enforce geometry data-type for column when using NetTopologySuite?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, nettopologysuite

I am currently using EntityFramework with NetTopologySuite.
I have a property called "Geometry" where the C#-type is set to NetTopologySuites "Geometry"-type..

```
public Geometry Geometry { get;set; }
```

Im using a code-first approach..
The problem is that when I run dotnet ef database update, the C#-geometry type gets "mapped" to the geography data-type of SQL Server.

So the column called "Geometry" is now of the data-type **geography**.. but I would very much prefer it to be of the SQL-Server data-type **geometry**.

Is it pssoible to somehow enforce my Geometry-property to be mapped to a geometry data-type?

Comment: `HasColumnType("geometry")`?

Comment: ...or `[Column(TypeName= "geometry")]`